# could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (100)

Tags: python, numpy, outliers

I am trying to remove outliers from each column of an array with dimensions (100,100).

My code is as follows:

```
for k in range(100): 
      array[:,k] = array[:,k][abs(array[:,k] - np.mean(array[:,k])) < 2 *  np.std(array[:,k])]
```

however I get this error:

could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (100). Any idea why? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't assign a subset of the `array[:,k]` column back on to itself.

Comment: Imagine 50/100 items pass the criterion for one column. How do you assign that back? What if 99/100 items pass on the next column. How do you combine 50 elements and 99 elements?

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty difficult to gauge what the intention is within the square brackets: `abs(array[:,k] - np.mean(array[:,k])) < 2 *  np.std(array[:,k]`. The `<` sign, evaluated in the end, turned the whole expression into a list of booleans, like `[True False True ...]`. It cannot be reassigned to the original numpy array.